# How to write rhead only on the first page?

Tags: fancyhdr

How to write rhead only on the first page? The other rheads should be nothing. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
text
\rhead{name}
\newpage
text
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\AtBeginShipoutFirst` of the `atbegshi` package we can execute some code while the first page is being output, e.g., we could do `\rhead{}` there:

```latex
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\rhead{name}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\rhead{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
text
\newpage
text
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

Use a different page style for the first page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for fill-in text

\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[R]{name}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

This is more flexible than other approaches.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this -

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}    
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\begin{center}
text
\rhead{name}
\newpage
text
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```